# can a BackgroundWorker object in c# be ran without a Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker, desktop-application

I need to develop a **C#** application using `**BackgrounWorker**`, but without using **Windows Forms**. I've seen some examples presented by Microsoft regarding the use of the BackgrounWorker class, and they're all developed specifically for Windows Forms. Can I use BackgroundWorker without Windows Forms ? if so, please provide some detail. thanks in advance !

Comment: The BackgroundWorker was designed for use with Windows Forms.  The ProgressChanged() and RunWorkerCompleted() events are automatically marshaled to the main UI thread so it is safe to interact with the UI.  If you have no UI then why use the BackgroundWorker?...where does the "need" to do this come from?  There are other options, such as manually creating [Threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx) or using [Tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your prompt and insightful response !!! The "need" comes from the fact that I inherited a **Windows Forms** application that uses **BackgroundWorker**, and I needed it to connect with another application in **asp.net Web-API**. However, these two frameworks cannot talk directly. So, I am trying to extract the code from the Windows Forms application to put it into a **"pure" c#** application. What is your suggestion between the 2 options: Threads and Tasks ?

Comment: Thread is the old school way of doing it.  If you have no compelling reason to be "old school", then definitely learn how to use Tasks.  See [SLaks Blog](http://blog.slaks.net/2013-10-11/threads-vs-tasks/) for some more insight on Task vs. ThreadPool, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C# there you can use [Tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx) they are both used to run in background in separated execution context ( separated thread )

This is an simple example for using thread

```
    using System.Threading;

     // creating new thread and pass it the delegate to run it 

    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WorkThreadFunction));
    // this command to start the thread
    thread.Start();

    public void WorkThreadFunction()
    {

        // do any background work

    }
```

Comment: **Hi Bakri**, thanks for your comments and the example ! I think I will use **Threads**.